# Unable to run a Robo script from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-test-lab, android-espresso-recorder

Unable to run a Robo script from Android Studio
I follow these recommended steps...

1. Open Android Studio and select Tools -> Firebase.
2. In the Firebase pane, click "Record Robo Script and Use it to Guide Robo Test".
3. Click Record Robo script. The Select Deployment Target dialog appears.

**That dialog does not appear!**
I do get this error [abbreviated] message in the Android Studio debug pane...
Error loading build artifacts from:
C:\AndroidStudioProjects...\debug\redirect.txt

I have set these...
Android Manifest: android:debuggable="true"
build variant: release
build.gradle: release, debuggable true

As recommended in another thread I tried this with similar results...
Espresso Test Recorder (Run -> Record Espresso Test).

**Update:** Since I tried the above Espresso Test
I now get this message **when I try to generate the Robo script**...
even after re-starting Android Studio...
**Could not launch Espresso Test Recorder**

Comment: Update: I just by accident found this Firebase notification message in my android studio. I do not understand it either :(
Couldn't find registrable Android clients in project.

Comment: No solution :(
I am most disappointed in the RoboScript members on this forum. I think they interpreted my post as a complaint, which it is not, it is a problem looking for a solution. I tried to go back to Robo again with no success and no assistance that time either :( I gave up, other things to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed both stable (Hedgehog | 2023.1.1.) and Nightly/Beta/Canary (Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Nightly) version of Android Studio IDE side by side using JetBrains's Toolbox utility.

Robo script wizard/dialog is not working on the stable version of the Android Studio, but it is working on the Nightly version of Android Studio.

[image]